# Partial fraction of $\frac{x^n}{(1-x)(1-2x)(1-3x)\ldots(1-nx)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, partial-fractions

How should you break $\displaystyle \frac{x^n}{(1-x)(1-2x)(1-3x)\ldots(1-nx)}$ into partial fractions?

Answer (score 8):

First you have to take out a multiple of the denominator to make the degree of the numerator smaller than that of the denominator:

$$\frac{x^n}{(1-x)(1-2x)(1-3x)\ldots(1-nx)}$$

$$= \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} + \frac{x^n-\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}(1-x)(1-2x)(1-3x)\ldots(1-nx)}{(1-x)(1-2x)(1-3x)\ldots(1-nx)}\;.$$

Now you can deal with the remaining fraction. You already have the denominator in factorized form, so you know the partial fraction expansion will have the form

$$\frac{a_1}{1-x}+\frac{a_2}{1-2x}+\frac{a_3}{1-3x}+\ldots+\frac{a_n}{1-nx}\;.$$

To get the coefficients $a_i$, you can use the fact that the residues of the poles must be equal to the corresponding residues in the fraction.

Comment: Can you explain more? What are residues and poles?

Comment: Roughly speaking, a pole is a point $x_0$ at which the function diverges like $c/(x-x_0)$, and the residue at the pole is the coefficient $c$. For instance, the function $f(x)=(x^2+3)/((x-1)(x-2))$ has poles at $1$ and $2$, and the corresponding residues are $-4$ and $7$, which you can calculate by substituting the pole $x_0$ into the function except for the "pole part" of it, $1/(x-x_0)$.

Comment: I should add that you can also calculate the coefficients $a_i$ by bringing the partial fractions onto a common denominator and then comparing coefficients of powers of $x$ in the numerator with the fraction you're expanding, but that's often more tedious than using the residues of the poles.

Answer (score 7):

To expand on joriki's comment, I claim that

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{1}{k}} \frac{x^n (1 - kx)}{(1 - x)...(1 - nx)} = a_k.$$

This is not hard to see by multiplying both sides by $1 - kx$. On the other hand, this limit is quite easy to compute since $1 - kx$ cancels, giving

$$a_k = \frac{1}{k(k-1)...(k-n)} = \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{k! (n-k)!}.$$

Note that this technique works to give you the partial fraction decomposition of any rational function, at least when the denominator has simple roots: instead of canceling a factor, you can just use l'Hopital's rule.

Note also that the function you're looking at happens to be the ordinary generating function of the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), and here you can cheat because you can also find their *exponential* generating function.

Answer (score 4):

It is worth emphasizing that both of the presented solutions essentially employ what is known as [Heaviside's cover-up method.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method) As I explained in [this answer,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23484/help-solving-int-frac8x415x316x222x4xx12x22dx/23498#23498) this method works generally, i.e. even for nonlinear denominators. As should be evident from the presentation that I gave there, the solution can be constructed by a purely *algebraic* deterministic algorithm, i.e. without employing any *analytic* techniques (residue calculus, limits, L'Hopital's rule, etc). Moreover, this is frequently the most efficient way to proceed - even for manual calculations.

Comment: @ Bill: Thanks for the helpful wiki article. It actually was 100% useful for a change :)