# Find the remainder of the division of $x^n+5$ with $x^3+10x^2+25x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the remainder of the division of $x^n+5$ with $x^3+10x^2+25x$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

What I tried to do is to write $x^n+5=p(x)(x^3+10x^2+25x)+Ax^2+Bx+C$, where $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n-3$. If I set $x=0$ I obtain that $C=5$.

Now $x^3+10x^2+25x=x(x+5)^2$ and by setting $x=-5$, I get that

$5A-B=(-1)^n5^{n-1}$

But I need one more equation to be able to find the coefficients of the remainder, and I can't get one. What should I do?

Comment: Don't you get $C=5$ by setting $x=0$?

Comment: Hint: differentiate, since $\,x = -5\,$ is a double root you can again evaluate at $\,x = -5\,$ to get  another equation in $A,B$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good idea to use the roots of $q(x)=x^3+10x^2+25x$, but yes: because $-5$ is a double root, things get a little bit trickier. (Also, check that setting $x=0$ gives $C=5$, not $C=0$).

HINT: But since $-5$ is a double root of $q$, it is both a root of $q$ and $q'$. So try to take the derivative at both members and then take again $x=-5$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Subtracting $\, C = 5\,$ then cancelling $x$ yields

$\qquad  f(x) := x^{\large n-1} = B + Ax + (x+5)^{\large 2} p(x)  $

Thus $\, B + Ax = f(-5) + f'(-5)(x+5)\,$ by Taylor expansion at $\,x = -5\,$

Comment: If you don't know (or can't use) Taylor then you could instead apply this (purely algebraic)  [Polynomial Double Root Test.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1139902/242) on $\,x^{n-1}\!-B-Ax,\,$ or just differentiate as I hinted on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in the attempt that is part of the question. Anyway, here are some relevant quotients and remainders:

$$  \left(   x^{4}  + 5 \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  + 10 x^{2}  + 25 x  \right)  \cdot   \left(   x  - 10 \right)  +  \left(  75 x^{2}  + 250 x  + 5 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{5}  + 5 \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  + 10 x^{2}  + 25 x  \right)  \cdot   \left(   x^{2}  - 10 x  + 75 \right)  +  \left(   - 500 x^{2}  - 1875 x  + 5 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{6}  + 5 \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  + 10 x^{2}  + 25 x  \right)  \cdot   \left(   x^{3}  - 10 x^{2}  + 75 x  - 500 \right)  +  \left(  3125 x^{2}  + 12500 x  + 5 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{7}  + 5 \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  + 10 x^{2}  + 25 x  \right)  \cdot   \left(   x^{4}  - 10 x^{3}  + 75 x^{2}  - 500 x  + 3125 \right)  +  \left(   - 18750 x^{2}  - 78125 x  + 5 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{8}  + 5 \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  + 10 x^{2}  + 25 x  \right)  \cdot   \left(   x^{5}  - 10 x^{4}  + 75 x^{3}  - 500 x^{2}  + 3125 x  - 18750 \right)  +  \left(  109375 x^{2}  + 468750 x  + 5 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{9}  + 5 \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  + 10 x^{2}  + 25 x  \right)  \cdot   \left(   x^{6}  - 10 x^{5}  + 75 x^{4}  - 500 x^{3}  + 3125 x^{2}  - 18750 x  + 109375 \right)  +  \left(   - 625000 x^{2}  - 2734375 x  + 5 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{10}  + 5 \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  + 10 x^{2}  + 25 x  \right)  \cdot   \left(   x^{7}  - 10 x^{6}  + 75 x^{5}  - 500 x^{4}  + 3125 x^{3}  - 18750 x^{2}  + 109375 x  - 625000 \right)  +  \left(  3515625 x^{2}  + 15625000 x  + 5 \right)  $$