# Remainder of polynomial division when divisor is square without calculus

Tags: polynomials

The problem is given as follows:

> Let $p(x) = x^{2004} - x^{1901} - 50$. What is the remainder of the 
>   division of $p(x)$ by $(x-1)^2$.

The solution is straightforward when using the derivative of $p(x)$. However, considering that I stumbled upon this problem in a high school textbook, I'm assuming that an elegant solution exists without the use of calculus?

Answer (score 2):

Let $$
x^{2004}-x^{1901}-50=q(x)(x-1)^2+ax+b.
$$ Translating by $-1$, we have
$$\begin{align*}
q(x+1)x^2+ax+(a+b)&=(x+1)^{2004}-(x+1)^{1901}-50\\&=\sum_{j=0}^{2004}\binom{2004}jx^j-\sum_{j=0}^{1901}\binom{1901}jx^j-50
\\&= \text{(higher order terms})+103x-50.
\end{align*}$$ This gives $a=103$ and $b=-153$.

Answer (score 2):

Write: $$x^{2004} - x^{1901} - 50 = (x-1)^2k(x)+ax+b$$

Setting $x=1$ we get $$-50 = a+b\implies b=-50-a$$

so $$x^{2004} - x^{1901} - 50 = (x-1)^2k(x)+ax-a-50$$

so  $$x^{1901}(x^{103}-1) = (x-1)^2k(x)+a(x-1)$$

so $$ x^{1901}(x^{102}+ x^{101}+...+x+1)= (x-1)k(x)+a$$

and finally putting $x=1$ again we get $$103 =a\implies r(x)=103x-153$$

Answer (score 2):

$x\!=\!1\,\Rightarrow\, p = -50 + (x\!-\!1)\color{#c00}g.\ $ $\, g = \dfrac{p+50}{x-1}=x^{1901}\,\dfrac{x^{103}\!-\!1}{x\!-\!1} = x^{1901}(x^{102}+\cdots+x+1)\,$

so  $\,x\!=\!1\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}g = 103+(x\!-\!1)h\ $ thus $\ p = -50+103(x\!-\!1)+(x\!-\!1)^2h$

Comment: We twice applied the **Remainder Theorem** $\,f(x) = f(1) = (x-1)g(x)\,$ for some polynomial $\,g(x)\ $  See also the [**Double Root Test**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1139902/242) in *algebraic* form.