# Describing all $f \in \mathbb{F}_2[x]$ divisible by $x^2 +1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, divisibility

As the title suggests, I want to describe all $f \in \mathbb{F}_2[x]$ divisible by $x^2 +1$. I am sure it's easy but I could't do it for like an hour so I wrote this question.

What I know.

1. It's easy for $x+1$ instead of $x^2+1$. In this case the answer is simply the polynomials with even number of nonzero coefficients.
2. The remainder is either $x+1$ or zero, therefore there is a bijection between polynomials I need to describe and polynomials I don't need which takes $f \mapsto f + (x+1)$ (the inverse map is the same).

Comment: Write $f(x)=g(x^2)+xh(x^2)$ for some $g,h\in\mathbb{F}_2[x]$. Note that $f(x)=(x^2+1)q(x)$ iff replacing $x^2=1$ you get $0$. So, this is the same as $g(1)=h(1)=0$. You can replace this condition by your condition (1) for $g$ and for $h$. So, the even part and the odd part of $f$ must both have an even number of non-zero coefficients.

Comment: Note that $x^2+1=(x+1)^2$ modulo $2$.

Comment: By the way, regarding your observation (2). If $f(x)=x(x^2+1)+1$ the remainder after division by $x^2+1$ is neither $x+1$ nor $0$. It is $1$. You can also see the possible remainders as the possible values of $g(x^2)+xh(x^2)$ when you replace $x^2=1$. The $g(1)$ and the $h(1)$ can take each of the values $0,1$.

Comment: @Boxwood, it is exactly how I know the bijection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, show that if $f(x)=f_0+f_1x+\dots+f_nx^n$, then
$$
f(x)\equiv (f_0+f_2+\dots)+x(f_1+f_3+\dots)\pmod{x^2+1}
$$
Conclude that $f(x)$ is a multiple of $x^2+1$ if and only if the sum of the even index coefficients is $0$, as well as the sum of the odd-index coefficients.

Comment: **Or** apply the [double root test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1139902/242) to infer $\,(x\!-\!1)^2\mid f(x)\iff f(1)=0= f'(1),\,$ and note $\bmod 2\!:\ f'(1)\equiv f_1 + f_3 + f_5 + \cdots $

Comment: **Please** have the courtesy to cite a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4320638/describing-all-f-in-mathbbf-2x-divisible-by-x2-1#comment9005789_4320638) when you duplicate it in an answer, esp. when it 's very old  (a couple hours here).

Comment: @BillDubuque I wrote this answer without looking at that comment.

Comment: Given that it is the *first* comment on the answer, that seems quite difficult to do even  when trying (I cannot force it outside my field of vision while reading the question). Please *do* read the comments since often they contain pertinent information necessary to formulate a good answer. Common site courtesy is to make such an answer CW and cite the comment.

Comment: Meh! Nobody is inventing anything new here and this site is a collaboration. Only the idea deserves reverence, if it works, and not the people. I certainly don't need any acknowledgement.