# Partial Fraction and Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, partial-fractions

I was going through the solution of a problem when I encountered this expression.

$${{f(x)} \over {(x - a)(x - b)(x - c)}}$$
Its given that $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $ < 3$.

This was simplified as follows -

> By partial fractions,  $${{f(x)} \over {(x - a)(x - b)(x - c)}} = {A \over {x - a}} + {B \over {x - b}} + {C \over {x - c}}$$
>   Then, $$A = {\left[ {{{f(x)} \over {(x - b)(x - c)}}} \right]_{x = a}} = {{f(a)} \over {(a - b)(a - c)}}$$
>   Similarly, $$B = {{f(b)} \over {(b - a)(b - c)}}\,\,{\rm{and}}\,\,C = {{f(c)} \over {(c - a)(c - b)}}$$

I think that the *division algorithm for polynomials* is involved here. But I could not understand how does the use of algorithm lead to substitution of $a,\,b\,{\rm{and}}\,c$ in place of $x$.

How does one get these expressions for $A,\,B\,{\rm{and}}\,C$?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20963/integration-by-partial-fractions-how-and-why-does-it-work, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313454/is-this-a-valid-partial-fraction-decomposition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$${{f(x)} \over {(x - a)(x - b)(x - c)}} = {A \over {x - a}} + {B \over {x - b}} + {C \over {x - c}}$$

Multiply by the denominator of lhs to get
$$f(x)=A(x - b)(x - c)+B(x - a)(x - c)+C(x - a)(x - b)$$

Since this is true for all $x$, then

$$f(a)=A(a-b)(a-c)\implies A= ???$$
$$f(b)=B(b-a)(b-c)\implies B= ???$$
$$f(c)=C(c-a)(c-b)\implies C= ???$$

Answer (score 3):

$${{f(x)} \over {(x - a)(x - b)(x - c)}} = {A \over {x - a}} + {B \over {x - b}} + {C \over {x - c}}$$

$${f(x)} = {A (x-b)(x-c)} + {B (x-a)(x-c)} + {C (x-a)(x-b)}$$

Now you can put $x=a,b,c$ to get $A,B,C$ respectively.

Comment: You won ! Two minutes too late. You are too fast for the old man ! Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks Sir!