# Find the integral $\int \frac{dx}{(x+a)^2(x+b)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Find THE integral

$\int \frac{dx}{(x+a)^2(x+b)^2}$

[image]

This is answer for this question at stackexchange.

My question is when multiply by $(x+a)^2(x+b)^2$ we assume that $x$ $\neq$ to $-a$ and $-b$.How then we can put $-a$ for $x$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313454/is-this-a-valid-partial-fraction-decomposition.

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks I am reading it now.