# Is there a fundamental difference between writing dividend=quotient$\cdot$divisor+remainder and dividend/divisor=quotient+remainder/divisor?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the division of 73 by 5. Commonly, one could think of the result as 14 with a remainder of 3. In equations, however, this would seem to be expressed as

$$\frac{73}{5}=14+\frac{3}{5}\tag{1}$$

This might be a question of semantics, but what is the remainder, $\frac{3}{5}$ or $3$?

It seems to me that the more intuitive way to express the division, which reflects the original common statement is:

$$73=14\cdot 5+3\tag{2}$$
Which says that 73 is 14 multiplied by 5 with a remainder of 3.

$(1)$ and $(2)$ also differ because if we were to write them in a more general way we'd get

$$\text{dividend}=\text{quotient} \cdot \text{divisor}+\text{remainder}\tag{3}$$

$$\frac{\text{dividend}}{\text{divisor}}=\text{quotient}+\frac{\text{remainder}}{\text{divisor}}\tag{4}$$

$(3)$ and $(4)$ differ because $(4)$ isn't defined for a divisor of zero, but $(3)$ is.

I don't know the relevant theorem for real numbers, but for polynomials there is the following theorem:

> (Spivak Calculus, Ch. 3, Problem 7a) For any polynomial function $f$, and any number $a$, there is a
> polynomial function $g$, and a number $b$, such that for all $x$
> $$f(x)=(x-a)g(x)+b\tag{5}$$

This basically says that given a polynomial $f$ and a factor $x-a$, there is a polynomial $g$ such that if we multiply $g(x)$ by the factor $x-a$ and add a remainder $b$, we get $f$.

It would seem to be more intuitive to interpret the theorem as saying that

> for any factor $x-a \neq 0$ we can always divide $f$ by $x-a$ and
> obtain quotient and a remainder.
>
> ie $$\frac{f(x)}{x-a}=g(x)+\frac{b}{x-a} \tag{6}$$

This latter interpretation doesn't seem to be equivalent to the theorem, because the theorem is true for all $x$, including $x=a$.

Can the theorem have been written using $6$ instead of $5$?

Comment: The advantage of (2) or (5) is that you do not leave the realm of integers or polynomials. As in, if you want to evenly split up a herd of 73 living sheep among 5 siblings and a fraction of a living sheep makes no sense, then it makes more sense to say that every sibling obtains 14 sheep and 3 sheep **remain** undistributed. -- Similarly, when you come up with (6), you run into trouble (as in someone objecting "Wait! That's not even defined at $x=a$!")

Comment: In fact $(6)$ is equivalent to $(5)$ if we are working with formal polynomials, or with polynomials over an infinite field (or domain). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/165141/242) for further discussion (in the context of the Heaviside cover-up method for partial fraction expansion).