# Showing that $\frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I have a simple development of an expression that I can not understand how it was made. The expression is:

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{k(k+1)} & = \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}     \end{align}$$

Can please someones show me how the left side is equal to the right side?

Thank you!

Comment: First introduction to partial fractions?

Comment: This is an example of a [partial fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction) expansion of a rational function, which is easily calculated by the [Heaviside cover-up method.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method) It deserves to be better known that this method [also works for *nonlinear* denominators.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/23498/242)

Comment: Thanks for you answers! Partial fractions are actually introduced later in my book. Still it was good to read up on them!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When adding two fractions, it is useful to use [common denominator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_denominator).

In your case, $k(k+1)$ is a multiple of both $k$ and $k+1$, so you can write:

$$\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}=\frac{k+1}{k(k+1)}-\frac{k}{k(k+1)}=\frac{(k+1)-k}{k(k+1)}=\frac{1}{k(k+1)}.$$

---

A slightly different approach: If you are given $\frac1{k(k+1)}$ and you want to simplify it, you may notice that $\frac{k+1}{k(k+1)}=\frac1k$ and $\frac{k}{k(k+1)}=\frac1{k+1}$ are simpler expressions. So you can ask whether you can somehow write the numerator using $k+1$ and $k$. And you can: $1=(k+1)-k$.

So you get
$$\frac1{k(k+1)} = \frac{(k+1)-k}{k(k+1)}=\frac{k+1}{k(k+1)}-\frac{k}{k(k+1)}=\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}.$$

Comment: Thank you! This was probably the way I was supposed to do it according to my book. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Recall how fractions are subtracted:
$$
   \frac{a}{b} - \frac{c}{d} = \frac{a \cdot d}{b \cdot d} - \frac{b \cdot c}{b \cdot d} = \frac{a \cdot d- b \cdot c}{b \cdot d}
$$
In the case at hand $a=c=1$, $b=k+1$ and $d=k$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!