# Rational function partial fraction help?

Tags: integration

So I have to integrate 
$$
\frac{3x+2}{(x)(x+1)^3}
$$ so I have the terms 
$$
\frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x+1} +\frac{C}{(x+1)^2} +\frac{D}{(x+1)^3}
$$ 
... and then I have 
$$
3x+2=A(x+1)^3 + B(x)(x+1)^2 +C(x)(x+1)^2+ D(x)(x+1)^2
$$
... here I tried to equal the quotients and I have $A=2$..how do I find the others?

Answer (score 3):

From $$
\frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x+1} +\frac{C}{(x+1)^2} +\frac{D}{(x+1)^3}
$$ you have: $$\frac{A(x+1)^3+Bx(x+1)^2+Cx(x+1)+Dx}{x(x+1)^3}=\frac{3x+2}{x(x+1)^3}$$ Now let $x=0$ then $$A(0+1)^3=3\times0+2\to A=2$$ Let $x=-1$ then $$D(-1)=3\times(-1)+2=-1\to D=-1$$ Set $x=1$ then $$8A+4B+2C+D=3\times1+2=5\to 16+4B+2C-1=5\to4B+2C=-10$$
Set $x=2$ then $$27A+18B+6C+2D=3\times 2+2=8\to 54+18B+6C-2=8\to18B+6C=-44$$ Now solve the two final equation respect to $B$ and $C$.

Answer (score 3):

You’re starting off on the wrong foot. When you put

$$\frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x+1} +\frac{C}{(x+1)^2} +\frac{D}{(x+1)^3}\tag{1}$$

back together into a single fraction, that fraction **must** have the same denominator as the original one. $(1)$ becomes

$$\frac{A(x+1)^3+Bx(x+1)^2+Cx(x+1)+Dx}{x(x+1)^3}\;.$$

and you want to choose $A,B,C$, and $D$ so that

$$\frac{A(x+1)^3+Bx(x+1)^2+Cx(x+1)+Dx}{x(x+1)^3}=\frac{3x+2}{x(x+1)^3}\;.$$

Two fractions **with the same denominator** are equal if and only their numerators are equal, so you require that

$$A(x+1)^3+Bx(x+1)^2+Cx(x+1)+Dx=3x+2\;.\tag{2}$$

Setting $x=0$, you find that $A=2$. Setting $x=-1$, you find that $-D=-1$, so $D=1$. Thus, $(2)$ reduces to

$$2(x+1)^3+Bx(x+1)^2+Cx(x+1)+x=3x+2\;,$$ or

$$2(x+1)^3+Bx(x+1)^2+Cx(x+1)=2x+2\;.$$ Now just multiply out the lefthand side:

$$2x^3+6x^2+6x+2+Bx^3+2Bx^2+Bx+Cx^2+Cx=2x+2\;,$$ or

$$(B+2)x^3+(2B+C+6)x^2+(B+C+4)x=0\;.$$

The coefficients on the righthand side are all $0$, so all that remains is to solve

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
&B+2=0\\
&2B+C+6=0\\
&B+C+4=0
\end{align*}\right.$$

for $B$ and $C$. The first equation makes this easy: $B=-2$, and then $C=-2$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ \ $ Evaluating the equation $\rm\ A(x\!+\!1)^3\!+Bx(x\!+\!1)^2\!+Cx(x\!+\!1)+Dx\:=\:3x\!+\!2 $ 
$$\begin{eqnarray} \rm at\ \ x&=&\ \ \ 0 &&\Rightarrow\rm\ \ \ \color{#C00}{A = 2}\\
\rm at\ \ x&=& {-}1 &&\Rightarrow\rm\ \ \ \color{#C00}{D = 1}\\  
\rm at\ \ x&=&\ \ \ 1 &&\Rightarrow\rm\ \ \ 4B +\rm 2C &=& -12\\
 \rm at\ \ x&=&-2&&\Rightarrow\rm -2B +\rm2C &=& 0\end{eqnarray}$$

Subtracting the last two yields $\rm\ 6B = -12\:\Rightarrow\: \color{#C00}{B = -2}\:\Rightarrow\: \color{#C00}{C = -2}$

**Remark** $\ $ Generally a polynomial of degree $n$ over $\Bbb Q$ is determined uniquely by its values at $n+1$ points. We judiciously chose the above points in order  to keep the arithmetic simple.

The first half is  the [Heaviside cover-up method,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method) which [can also be applied to nonlinear factors](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/23498/23500).