# Problems solving partial fraction

Tags: partial-fractions

I have a problem with partial decomposition, I got the next function and should integrate the function so it would be easier to split it in two terms. But I have no idea to start this decomposition due to the unknown a.

$\frac{1}{(x+a)(x+1)}$ with $a>0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using  [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html)

$$\frac1{(x+a)(x+1)}=\frac A{x+a}+\frac B{x+1}$$

Multiplying eithersides by $(x+a)(x+1),$ we get $$1=A(x+1)+B(x+a)=x(A+B)+A+Ba$$

Now compare the constants & the coefficients of $x$

---

As $x+a-(x+1)=a-1$

by observation  $$\frac1{(x+a)(x+1)}=\frac1{a-1}\left(\frac{(x+a)-(x+1)}{(x+a)(x+1)}\right)=\cdots$$

Comment: I know, but I have problems to find the A and B

Comment: @user2239704, please find the edited version

Comment: With this solution its almost more difficult to get the integral of the solution..

Comment: @user2239704, do you mean "Integration"? Then do you know what is $$\int\frac A{x+a}dx$$

Comment: I think it is A*ln(x+a)

Comment: @user2239704, do you have anymore confusion?

Comment: so is it possible to just take the integral of A/(x+a) and then fill A in after the integration?

Comment: @user2239704, why don't try & then differentiate the answer to validate the process:)

Comment: Yeah it is the same because you can take the A out of function before you differentiate, so I guess its the same for the integral

Comment: @user2239704, nice to hear that

Answer (score 0):

First Write
$\frac{C}{x+a}+\frac{D}{x+1}$ and then solve

$(C+D)x+(C+Da)=1$

$ C+D=0$ and $ C+aD=1$

Comment: yes but I do not found the C and D for this problem.. I know D = (1-C)/a but I cannot go further

Comment: $D=-C$ so $C(1-a)=1$ which implies that $C=\frac{1}{1-a}$ and $D=\frac{-1}{1-a}$

So in the end you get
$\frac{1}{(x+a)(x+1)}=\frac{1}{1-a}(\frac{1}{x+a}-\frac{1}{x+1})$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ By [Heaviside](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method) $\ \dfrac1{(\color{#c00}{x\!-\!a})(\color{#0a0}{x\!-\!b})}=\dfrac A{x-a}+\dfrac B{x-b}\ $ $\Rightarrow$ $\,\ A = \dfrac{1}{a\color{#0a0}{-b}},\ B =\dfrac{1}{b\color{#c00}{-a}} = -A$

**Remark** $\ $ It deserves to be better known that the Heaviside cover-up method can be [generalized to handle nonlinear denominators.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/23498/242)