# How do I integrate $\frac{8x^2}{(x^2+1)^3}$ using partial fraction expansion?

Tags: calculus

My textbook says that any rational function can be integrated using partial fraction expansion. So I was eager to try this out. But I got stuck with my very first example. How do I integrate $\frac{8x^2}{(x^2+1)^3}$ using partial fraction expansion?

Comment: Can you perform the expansion ?

Comment: May help https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1776522/108128.

Comment: Yep. $\frac{8}{(x^2+1)^2}-\frac{8}{(x^2+1)^3}$

Comment: @Adam Over complex factors ?

Comment: We didn't learn about that...

Comment: @Adam Then you are stuck with the partial fraction that you got in your last comment.

Comment: time to learn it, I guess...

Comment: @Adam If you to solve this question then make $x = \tan \theta$ substitution.

Comment: I know, I already solved it using this. But I wanted to try using partial fraction expansion.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/689932/1242