# help reducing by modulo

Tags: modular-arithmetic, partial-fractions

I'm an engineer, not a math guy.  Please use small words if possible.  ;-)

I am going through [this neat paper](https://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation.aspx?paperid=67732) on a method of partial fraction decomposition by repeated synthetic division.  On page 157 it is covering case with repeated irreducible quadratics in denominator - and it says this:

> "Multiply both sides by the denominator...then
> We reduce the right hand side modulo $x^2+bx+c $ by sending it to the field $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2+bx+c) = 
> $ {$px+q|p,q\in \mathbb{R},x^2+bx+c=0$}. Modulo $x^2+bx+c$....

I have no clue how to "reduce the r.h.s. modulo by sending it to the field".   Can someone give me example of how to do such?  Preferably with real equations i can ponder like an engineer.

**UPDATE 1**:  Adding real example we can use.
Let,
$$\frac{N(s)}{D(s)}=\frac{10(s+1)}{(s+1)^3(s^2+5s+6)^3}=\frac{K_1}{s+1}+\frac{K_2}{(s+1)^2}+\frac{K_3}{(s+1)^3}+\frac{M_1s+C_1}{s^2+5s+6}+\frac{M_2s+C_2}{(s^2+5s+6)^2}+\frac{M_3s+C_3}{(s^2+5s+6)^3}$$

Multiplying both sides by D(s) I get,
$$N(s) = 10(s+3) = K_1(s+1)^2(s^2+5s+6)^3+K_2(s+1)(s^2+5s+6)^3+K_3(s^2+5s+6)^3+(M_1s+C_1)(s+1)^3(s^2+5s+6)^2+(M_2s+C_2)(s+1)^3(s^2+5s+6)+(M_3s+C_3)(s+1)^3$$

How do i proceed now?

Comment: Please give more context: which of these topics do you know:  congruences / modular arithmetic,  rings, fields, ideals, equivalence relation, quotient rings,

Comment: You may find of interest [this related post where](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/23498/242) I show how to extend to *nonlinear* denominators the Heaviside cover-up method for partial fraction decomposition, by using modular polynomial arithmetic.

Comment: Hi Bill, I understand modular arithmetic and congruence, but that’s about all from your list.

Comment: It just means to divide the polynomial by $x^2+bx +c$ and consider only the remainder, which will be a polynomial of degree at most $1$.  It's entirely analogous to modular arithmetic.

Comment: i.e. use congruences modulo $\,x^2+bx+c,\,$  where $\,x^2 \equiv -bx -c\,$. Such congruences work the same was as for integers, i.e. we have the [congruence sum and product rules, etc](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque  i have added an UPDATE 1 with real equations we can work with.  I don't know how to proceed as you suggest in your comments.  Can you help?

Comment: @saulspatz - see my UPDATE 1 above and my comment to Bill.

Comment: I don't know if this matters, but your example doesn't have an irreducible quadratic in the denominator.  $s^2+5s+6=(s+2)(s+3)$

Comment: @saulspatz I know, just trying to find example to learn the method....the actual mechanics of the process.  Can you help?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know anything about this, and I'm really not interested enough to read the paper.  I took a quick look at it, but I didn't understand the sentence you're asking about, either.  I'd need to read the paper to figure out the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
   10(s+3)
        &= K_1(s+1)^2(s^2+5s+6)^3 \\
        & +K_2(s+1)(s^2+5s+6)^3 \\
        &+ K_3(s^2+5s+6)^3 \\
        &+ (M_1s+C_1)(s+1)^3(s^2+5s+6)^2 \\
        &+ (M_2s+C_2)(s+1)^3(s^2+5s+6) \\
        &+ (M_3s+C_3)(s+1)^3
\end{align}$$

Let $s = -1$ and you get $20 = 8K_3$. So $K_3 = \dfrac 52$

$$\begin{align}
   10(s+3)
        &= K_1(s+1)^2(s^2+5s+6)^3 \\
        & +K_2(s+1)(s^2+5s+6)^3 \\
        &-\dfrac 52(s^2+5s+6)^3 \\
        &+ (M_1s+C_1)(s+1)^3(s^2+5s+6)^2 \\
        &+ (M_2s+C_2)(s+1)^3(s^2+5s+6) \\
        &+ (M_3s+C_3)(s+1)^3
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
   -\dfrac 52 (s + 3) (s + 1) (s^4 + 11 s^3 + 46 s^2 + 88 s + 68)
        &= K_1(s+1)^2(s^2+5s+6)^3 \\
        & +K_2(s+1)(s^2+5s+6)^3 \\
        &+ (M_1s+C_1)(s+1)^3(s^2+5s+6)^2 \\
        &+ (M_2s+C_2)(s+1)^3(s^2+5s+6) \\
        &+ (M_3s+C_3)(s+1)^3
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
   -\dfrac 52 (s + 3)(s^4 + 11 s^3 + 46 s^2 + 88 s + 68)
        &= K_1(s+1)(s^2+5s+6)^3 \\
        & +K_2(s^2+5s+6)^3 \\
        &+ (M_1s+C_1)(s+1)^2(s^2+5s+6)^2 \\
        &+ (M_2s+C_2)(s+1)^2(s^2+5s+6) \\
        &+ (M_3s+C_3)(s+1)^2
\end{align}$$

Let $s=-1$ again and you get...

### Added 11/22/2020

Your original equation is wrong. It should look like

\begin{align}
   \frac{10}{(s+1)^2 (s+2)^3 (s+3)^3} &=\\
   &\frac{K_1}{(s+1)} + \frac{K_2}{(s+1)^2} + \\
   &\frac{L_1}{(s+2)} + \frac{L_2}{(s+2)^2} + \frac{L_3}{(s+2)^3} + \\
   &\frac{M_1}{(s+3)} + \frac{M_2}{(s+3)^2} + \frac{M_3}{(s+3)^3}
\end{align}

You then get the equation

\begin{align}
   10 &=
   K_1(s+1)(s+2)^2 (s+3)^3 \\
   &+ K_2(s+2)^3 (s+3)^3 + \\
   &+ L_1(s+1)^2 (s+2)^2 (s+3)^3 \\
   &+ L_2(s+1)^2 (s+2) (s+3)^3 \\
   &+ L_3(s+1)^2 (s+3)^3 \\
   &+ M_1 (s+1)^2 (s+2)^3 (s+3)^2 \\
   &+ M_2 (s+1)^2 (s+2)^3 (s+3) \\
   &+ M_3 (s+1)^2 (s+2)^3  \\
\end{align}

Now let $s=-1$. You get $10=8K_2 \implies K_2 = \dfrac 54$. Simplifying, we get

\begin{align}
   \dfrac 58 (s + 1) (9 s^5 + 124 s^4 + 685 s^3 + 1902 s^2 + 2668 s + 1528) &=
   K_1(s+2)^3 (s+3)^3 \\
   &+ L_1(s+1) (s+2)^2 (s+3)^3 \\
   &+ L_2(s+1) (s+2) (s+3)^3 \\
   &+ L_3(s+1) (s+3)^3 \\
   &+ M_1 (s+1) (s+2)^3 (s+3)^2 \\
   &+ M_2 (s+1) (s+2)^3 (s+3) \\
   &+ M_3 (s+1) (s+2)^3  \\
\end{align}

Again let $s=-1$. You get $-45 = 8K_1 \implies K_1 = -\dfrac{45}{8}$. Simplifying, we get

\begin{align}
   -\dfrac 54 (4 + s)(52 + 70 s + 39 s^2 + 10 s^3 + s^4)
   &= L_1 (s+2)^2 (s+3)^3 \\
   &+ L_2 (s+2) (s+3)^3 \\
   &+ L_3 (s+3)^3 \\
   &+ M_1 (s+2)^3 (s+3)^2 \\
   &+ M_2 (s+2)^3 (s+3) \\
   &+ M_3 (s+2)^3  \\
\end{align}