# Partial fraction decomposition with algebraic structure ring and modulo

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ring-theory, partial-fractions, rational-functions

I know that an exercise like this
\begin{gather*}
\frac{5x^2 - 12x + 6}{(x - 2) (x - 1) (2 x - 3)}
\end{gather*}
is resolvable with several approaches the Heaviside "Cover-up method" e.g.
\begin{align*}
\frac{5x^2 - 12x + 6}{(x - 2) (x - 1) (2 x - 3)} &= \frac{5x^2 - 12x + 6}{2(x - 2) (x - 1) (x - 3/2)} \\[1ex]
&= \frac{A}{x - 2} + \frac{B}{x - 1} + \frac{C}{x - 3/2}
\end{align*}
to estimate the unknown constant "A" appling the rule:
\begin{gather*}
A = \left. \frac{5x^2 - 12x + 6}{2 (x - 1) (x - 3/2)} \right|_{x = 2} = \frac{5 (2)^2 - 12 (2) + 6}{2 ((2) - 1) ((2) - 3/2)} = 2
\end{gather*}
It works fine, but I'm interested to understand if is possible use the modulo with an inverted function like this:
\begin{align*}
A &= \left. \frac{5x^2 - 12x + 6}{2 (x - 1) (x - 3/2)} \right|_{x - 2 = 0}
\end{align*}
In the follow I'm looking for the unknown constant $\alpha$:
\begin{gather*}
(x - 2)(x - \alpha) = x^2 - (\alpha + 2) x + 2\alpha = 0\qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad x^2 - (\alpha + 2) x = - 2\alpha \\[1ex]
x^2 - (\alpha + 2) x \equiv x^2 - \frac{12}{5}x \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad - (\alpha + 2) = - \frac{12}{5} \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad \alpha = \frac{2}{5} \\[1ex]
-10\alpha = 5 \left( x^2 - (\alpha + 2) x \right) = 5x^2 - 12x \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad 5x^2 - 12x = -4
\end{gather*}
and so:
\begin{align*}
A &= \frac{-4 + 6}{2 (x - 1) (x - 3/2)} = \frac{1}{(x - 1) (x - 3/2)} \pmod{(x - 2)}
\end{align*}
At this point I don't know to proceed or I have mistraked.

Could you improve the resolution? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's simpler to first clear denominators before modding out (i.e. evaluating via the polynomial remainder theorem), e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/23498/242), which also shows how to extend Heaviside to *nonlinear* denominator factors.

Comment: Calculating polynomials mod x-2 or evaluating them at 2 is essentialy the same (just a bit longer). You did it for the numerator, you can do the same for the denominator.

Comment: It's not clear exactly why you are stuck. Are you using a method that evaluates via the *polynomial* remainder theorem (i.e. $f(a) = f(x)\bmod x\!-\!a),\,$ and you are not sure how to apply that to *quotients* of polynomials ("rational functions")?  [this is what I guessed in my first comment].

Comment: @Bill Dubuque - Unfortunately I'm stuck on polynomial remainder theorem. Thank you very much for the link I'm studying your answer to the other question.

Comment: @Anne Bauval - Thanks for your suggestion, I don't know how resolve with the modulo (x - 2) and I have try to solve it in that way to understand the difficulty.